# Django reverse OneToOneField lookup in unicode method

Tags: python, django

I have schedule and event models like this.

```
class Schedule(models.Model):
    jan = models.FloatField(default=2.0)
    feb = models.FloatField(default=2.0)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Some boring value'

class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    schedule = models.OneToOneField(schedule, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

In my admin view, I want to add the schedule in an EventAdmin class in a collapsed fashion like this.

```
class ScheduleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
    ('Schedule', {'fields': ['jan','feb']}),
    ]      

class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
    ('Event', {'fields': ['name',]}),
    ('Add schedule', {'fields': ['jan','feb'], 'classes': ['collapse']}),
    ]
```

So when I add a schedule to an event, I want the schedule **str** method to return the related Event.name field in the admin form, instead of just 'Some boring value' as it does now.

I also really only want to assign a schedule object once to an Event, instead of the form in admin showing a list of other schedules for other events - I have to disable the add and edit functionality if a schedule is added to an event.

I use admin.TabularInline sometimes, and maybe I should try using this method instead, because it also does not register Schedules in the admin (which I'm not really interested in either) - but this will return the error that 'Schedule has no foreign key to Event' and I have not found a way to solve reverse lookups in the admin yet either.

What would be the correct way to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

> So when I add a schedule to an event, I want the schedule str method to return the related Event.name field in the admin form, instead of just 'Some boring value' as it does now.

Add `related_name='event'` to your `models.OneToOneField` relation, so you can replace `return 'Some boring value'` with `return self.event.name`.

As for:

> I also really only want to assign a schedule object once to an Event, instead of the form in admin showing a list of other schedules for other events - I have to disable the add and edit functionality if a schedule is added to an event.

It's not very clear what you want to achieve here.

Comment: This yields an error ' Schedule has no event'. Regarding clarity: Events should only have 1 schedule. By default the admin form displays a list of all schedules for all events - I only want to assign one schedule to one event and have the possibility to edit or delete the schedule once it is created. It should not be possible to add more than 1 schedule to an event. Also by registering the Schedule and ScheduleAdmin classes in admin.py this creates a section 'Schedules' where I can add schedules without them being associated with an event - this makes no sense in this case.